# Why shorebird not finding file libapp.so?

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-dependencies, shorebird

i have a problem with shorebird flutter, the path of libapp.so that shorebird looking for is different from my machine path ?

Path to this file on my machine is : /Users/jean/Desktop/projects/nightfleet/build/app/intermediates/stripped_native_libs/release/stripReleaseDebugSymbols/out/lib/arm64-v8a/libapp.so, can you help me please ?

Path where shorebird looking for :

/Users/jean/Desktop/projects/nightfleet/build/app/intermediates/stripped_native_libs/release/out/lib/arm64-v8a/libapp.so

Can some one help me ?

i tried every thing but i didn't find solution [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C3Lnp.png)

Comment: Don't add image, insert code.